# NASM "hello world" in DOSBox

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox

I am trying to write a program in NASM for DOSBox for education purposes, a simple "hello world".

```
section .data
    hello db 'Hello, World!', 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Print the message to the screen
    mov ah, 9       ; AH=9 means "print string" function
    mov dx, hello   ; Load the offset address of 'hello' into DX
    int 21h         ; Call the DOS interrupt 21h to execute the function

    ; Exit the program
    mov ah, 4Ch     ; AH=4Ch means "exit" function
    xor al, al      ; Set AL to 0 (return code)
    int 21h         ; Call the DOS interrupt 21h to exit the program
```

Compiling in DOSBox with command:
`nasm -f bin hello.asm -o hello.com`

Running just typing:
`hello.com`

But instead of "Hello, World!" I am getting gibberish output (a lot of random characters). What's the reason and how to fix it?

**UPD**: Solved by adding `org 100h` and suffixing the message with a dollar sign.

Comment: IIRC, that function expects the string to be terminated with a `$`.

Comment: The convention of `_start` as an entry point isn't applicable to a DOS .COM executable, which simply starts executing with the first byte of the file.  I'm not sure how `nasm -f bin` arranges sections, but there's no reason to expect it would put `.text` first.

Comment: @NateEldredge In my tests it actually did order the `.text` section first. If you let NASM (or its internal `-f bin` format linker, anyway) write a map file you can notice that it always includes a `.text` section, even if you never defined a section of that name. I am not entirely certain about the causation here but I believe this may be related to the default ordering putting an explicit `.text` section before an explicit `.data` section (absent any `follows=` attributes), even if (as here) the `.data` section is specified first.

Comment: @NateEldredge Just checked, if you change the section names to "mydata" and "mytext" then the data section is written first. [The manual does say](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.1.3) "Any code which comes before an explicit SECTION directive is directed by default into the `.text` section." which relates to my observation that `.text` is always defined. Other than that it says "The bin format allows the use of multiple sections, of arbitrary names, besides the "known" `.text`, `.data`, and `.bss` names." but doesn't explicitly say `.text` is ordered first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to create a COM program, then you're missing a few important lines at the beginning

```
org 100h
entry: jmp _start

hello db 'Hello, World!$'

_start:
```

I haven't programmed in Assembly language 30 years and I don't remember a 'section' definition, but looking at some old code of mine, you need the 'org 100h' to leave room for the PSP. The line following (entry:) means 'jump over your data definitions to the beginning of the code'.

The gibberish that you saw was either an attempt to execute the PSP as code, or the 'hello' string as code.

Also, a string being sent to function 9 has to be terminated with a dollar sign, so it could be that your code 'executes' the data statement and continues onwards showing random data (whatever was in memory previously) until a dollar sign is reached.

Comment: "The gibberish that you saw was either an attempt to execute the PSP as code," No, that would require a negative jump (short or near) to before the position the code is loaded. DOS will execute starting at cs = PSP and ip = 256, so it is not accurate to say "the PSP" could get executed as code here. The `org` directive as well as the dollar sign terminator are what is missing here. The `jmp` before the data is not needed in NASM (at least the most recent revision based on version 2.16.01) as the `.text` section is written out before the `.data` section in the `-f bin` multi-section format.

Comment: DOS was a long time ago for me, but didn't you have to explicitly set DS too?  Something like `mov ax, @data | mov ds, ax`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Not for "tiny model" or flat-format .COM executables, if they use only the single segment. CS = DS = ES = SS = PSP on startup for those. MZ .EXE executables often have a data segment that cannot be addressed by the registers as DOS passes them, DS = ES = PSP. (The MZ .EXE CS and SS depend on the header fields for those registers.)

Comment: @ecm and @No'am - The "garbage" printed was probably the PSP *as data* (not code), due to the missing `org 100h` in the OP's code.  Without that the default is `org 0`, so `mov dx, hello` assembles to `mov dx, 0`, passing the address of the PSP to the DOS function.  Since it won't stop until it finds a `'$'`, it'll copy plenty of stuff to the screen.

Comment: `jmp _start` is a waste of 2 bytes; just put your data *after* the code unless you need it at a fixed location in the binary.  (Like `section .data` / `section .text` already does with NASM `-fbin`, but since you're making a .com flat binary, might be best to just explicitly put it at the bottom, after the exit system call.)

Comment: Thank you! org 100h and dollar sign helped. It seems to work good without jmp instruction

Comment: @Troir: yup, that's correct, as discussed in comments, NASM `-fbin` lays out the sections with `.text` first, so your ASCII data isn't executed as machine code.  It's probably a good idea to comment your code to note that, if you still want to keep the data ahead of the code in the .asm source.

Comment: @PeterCordes You can explicitly declare `section .data follows=.text` to insure the correct order. "so `mov dx, hello` assembles to `mov dx, 0`," - Actually you get `mov dx, 10h` because of the section layout.

Comment: @PeterCordes Tried for experiment to put data section in the end of file, still getting gibberish output. Also, as I read from books global _start is the place where program should start, so why it does not jump directly to it without skipping PSP?

Comment: @Troir: `org 100h` is necessary for `mov dx, hello` to put the correct address into DX.  Source order of sections doesn't matter; as discussed in comments NASM lays out a flat binary with `.text` first (my first comment guessed wrong that source order mattered, but it doesn't).  The PSP is *not* being executed as code, this answer is wrong about that, as my earlier comments already said.  So IDK why you're asking me about that.  re: `_start:` you're making a flat binary so there's no room for metadata.  Execution starts with the first byte of the file at IP=`100h`, with CS=DS=ES=SS.

Comment: @Troir: Have you tried running the program under a debugger? That would give you a good idea of not only where your program actually starts but also what is displayed by 21h/09.

Comment: @No'amNewman No, but I will, thank you for suggestion